# Replace newline with backspace to previous line

Tags: java, android, android-checkbox

I have a checkbox named Chocolate in my app. When it is checked it prints "Chocolate added!\n". But when i uncheck it after checked, and replace it with "" (no string) then it gets replaced on a new line. And the no. of lines keep on increasing on each check/uncheck. 
So my question is How to replace the whole string with a backspace? Such that next item should be printed instead of Chocolate on the same line.

```java
public void onCheck(View checkView) {

    String checkMessage = "";
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) checkView).isChecked();
    checkMessage += "\n";

    switch (checkView.getId()) {

        case R.id.chocolate:
            if (checked) {
                checkMessage += "Chocolate added.\n";
            } 
            else {
                checkMessage = checkMessage.replaceAll("Chocolate added.\n", "");
            }
            break;
    }
    checkMessage += "\n";
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is the lines that have: checkMessage += "\n";
This seems from your code, to add a newline to the string checkMessage, regardless of whether the checkbox is checked. Since you seem to have two of them, the number of lines will increase by 2 on every check/uncheck. So unless there is a use for them, deleting them will stop the lines from increasing.

Alternatively, to answer your question directly, the java escape sequence for a backspace is \b, however I do not know if adding that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove both of the `checkMessage += "\n";` . As it serve no purpose